# Unity wont send anything to my arduino

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arduino

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

public class Sending : MonoBehaviour 
{

public static SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600);


void Start () 
{
    OpenConnection();
}


public void OpenConnection() 
{
    if (sp != null) 
    {
        if (sp.IsOpen) 
        {
            sp.Close();
        }
        else 
        {
            sp.Open(); 
        }
    }
}


void OnApplicationQuit() 
{
    sp.Close();
}

public static void Contact(float AngleFloat)
{
    int AngleInt = (int)AngleFloat;
    string AngleStr = AngleInt.ToString ();
    Debug.Log(AngleStr);
    sp.Write(AngleStr);
}
}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class rotate : MonoBehaviour {
private float baseAngle = 0.0f;

void OnMouseDown()
{
    Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
    pos = Input.mousePosition - pos;
    baseAngle = Mathf.Atan2(pos.y, pos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    baseAngle -= Mathf.Atan2(transform.right.y, transform.right.x) *Mathf.Rad2Deg;
}

float OnMouseDrag()
{
    Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
    pos = Input.mousePosition - pos;
    float ang = Mathf.Atan2(pos.y, pos.x) *Mathf.Rad2Deg - baseAngle;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(ang, Vector3.forward);
    return ang;
}

void OnMouseUp()
{
    float ang = OnMouseDrag();
    Debug.Log(ang);
    Sending.Contact(ang);
}


}
```

Hi Everyone, I have a Unity Scene with a cube , i can drag to rotate the cube and when i release the mouse,  it send his new angle to my arduino who control a little motor. There are my two scripts .

My problem is , : I have always the same error : InvalidOperationException : Specified port is not Open.

I'm kinda new on unity to arduino so maybe the answer is obvious.
(Excuse my english, French here)

Thank you

EDIT : i'm adding my arduino code maybe the problem is here

```
int motorPin1 = 8;
int motorPin2 = 9;
int motorPin3 = 10;
int motorPin4 = 11;
int delayTime = 2;
int lf = 10;
int i = 0;

char myCol[20];

float angle = 5.625;


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin (9600);
  pinMode(motorPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorPin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorPin3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorPin4, OUTPUT);



}

void loop()
{

Serial.readBytesUntil(lf, myCol,4);
int ValeurUnity = atoi(myCol);
int Tickinv = (int)((ValeurUnity*8)/angle);


int Tick;
  if (Tickinv < 0)
  {
    Tick = abs(Tickinv);
  }
  if (Tickinv > 0)
  {
    Tick = (Tickinv * (-1));
  }
  if (Tickinv == 0)
  {
    Tick = 0;
  }

  if (i < Tick)
  {
    digitalWrite(motorPin1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motorPin2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motorPin3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorPin4, LOW);
    delay(delayTime);
    digitalWrite(motorPin1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorPin2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motorPin3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motorPin4, LOW);
    delay(delayTime);
    digitalWrite(motorPin1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorPin2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorPin3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motorPin4, HIGH);
    delay(delayTime);
    digitalWrite(motorPin1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motorPin2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorPin3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorPin4, HIGH);
    delay(delayTime);
    Serial.println(Tick);
    i++;
  }
  if (i > Tick)
  {
    digitalWrite(motorPin1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motorPin2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motorPin3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorPin4, LOW);
    delay(delayTime);
    digitalWrite(motorPin1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motorPin2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorPin3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorPin4, HIGH);
    delay(delayTime);
    digitalWrite(motorPin1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorPin2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorPin3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motorPin4, HIGH);
    delay(delayTime);
    digitalWrite(motorPin1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorPin2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motorPin3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motorPin4, LOW);
    delay(delayTime);
    i--;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you use the right COM port?

Comment: Yes, COM3 for unity , my arduino is on COM3 too

Comment: Is this on Windows, Mac or Linux?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. It works on my side. What windows version, Unity version and Arduino board are you using? Also are you trying this from the Editor or build?

Comment: i'm trying from the editor

Comment: Replay..... **What windows version, Unity version and Arduino board are you using?**

Comment: those are 3 questions you have never answered not an answer or statement....

Comment: Sorry i didnt see : 
Windows 7 Pro
Unity 4
Arduino/Genuino Uno

Comment: We have the-same thing except Unity version. Can you update to the Unity version? This should solve your problem

Comment: i'm gonna try, i'll tell you if it's working

Comment: Always the same error, and my arduino doesnt receive anything

Comment: Please use @Programmer while replying to me so that I will be notified. You updated to **Unity 5.4** and you are still getting the-same error?

Comment: @Programmer yes same error in Unity 5.4

Comment: Nice. Look at my answer. Please try all of those from step 1 to 5. Let me know if you are still having a problem.

Comment: Just a detail, but your OpenConnection function closes the port if it's already open. public void OpenConnection() 
{
    if (sp != null) 
    {
        if (sp.IsOpen) 
        {
            sp.Close();
        } Not sure that was your intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 4 possible things that might be causing this error.

**1**. Arduino program is Open. Close it then to run your program from Unity again.

**2**. Another Application is using the port. Please restart your computer to make sure that no other Application is using the port. After re-starting, don't open the Arduino App. Simply open Unity and try to run your program again.

**3**. You attached your script (`Sending`) to multiple **GameObjects**. Make sure that the `Sending` script is only attached to one GameObject. To verify this, create a simple new project and attach `Sending` script to one **GameObject** only.

**4**. You connecting to a different port. Make sure that the port you are connecting to is the Arduino port. Look at the image below for reference.

[image]

Comment: @Sholyu Nice. You can accept this as the answer by ticking the checkmark. http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Comment: Done !Thanks again !

Comment: @Sholyu You are welcome. Did this solve the problem you have in your new question?

Comment: @Sholyu Will give it a try in a moment

Comment: ok just tell me if you need my Unity Code , it's not the same project

Comment: @Sholyu I will. just busy right now. Why not edit that question and put your Unity code and Arduino code so that when I return, I will just replicate the problem on my side and see what's going on. Maybe in 5 hours.